# Problem with Visual studio 2019 and crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I have an application that was working fine.  It was written in Visual Studio 2017 to read a SQLite database and generate reports using crystal reports.  All was good....and then my development laptop went away.  I've attempted to migrate to a new box, both were/are Win10 64 bit.  I had to move to Visual Studio 2019 but seems compatible with 2017.  I've gotten to the point where I can load, display my app and filter the database but when I try to generate a report I get the following message which isn't helping me.  Note: This is not a web app, database etc. all on local machine.  Any ideas out there?  Thanks for any suggestions!

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=
  StackTrace:

Answer (score 0):

What service pack? If you are on the latest SP26, you need to use 13.0.4000.0 rather than 13.0.3500.0 references.